# ALSA: How to start Rx for (USB) raw MIDI?

Tags: linux, midi, alsa

I want to send MIDI SysEx messages from a Linux PC to a device that provides an USB MIDI interface.

The basic idea is that I send a SysEx message to the device and then receive the response like shown in this very simplified example:

```
handle = open("/dev/midiXxx", O_RDWR);
write(f, "\xF0...\xF7", LENGTH_OF_MESSAGE_1);
read(f, response1, sizeof(response1));
write(f, "\xF0...\xF7", LENGTH_OF_MESSAGE_1);
read(f, response2, sizeof(response2));
```

My problem is that the first `read()` sometimes hangs. By inserting `sleep()` in some parts of the program, I found out that the MIDI driver seems to discard all bytes received until `read()` is called the first time. If the device sends the response before the `read()` function is called in my program (for example because a task switch is happening exactly between the first `write()` and the first `read()`), the response is lost.

I saw this behavior ...

- Using `/dev/midiXxx`
- Opening `/dev/snd/midiCXxxDxxx` (and using `read()` and `write()`) directly
- Using ALSA's `snd_rawmidi_Xxx()` API instead of `open()`, `read()` and `write()`
  (This API internally accesses `/dev/snd/midiCXxxDxxx`)

My question:

**What is the correct method to ensure that the MIDI data is read?**

I tried two methods that have worked:

One method was using `O_NONBLOCK`, calling `read()` (returning `EWOULDBLOCK`) and then using `fcntl(F_SETFL)` to make the file handle "non-`O_NONBLOCK`" (because I don't want `O_NONBLOCK` in the rest of my program).

The other method was to call `poll()` with `POLLIN` before the `write()`.

However, I am not sure if these methods work reliably (especially after a Linux update).